# Sort a <b-table> in Bootstrap-Vue by a column and disallow user sort

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I know that we can make the columns of `<b-table>` sortable by using `:sort-by="sortBy"`. But how can I tell it to just sort the table by a particular column in the beginning and that too in descending order?

I tried the following, but that doesn't work.

```
<b-table
....
:default-sort="TheColumnToSort"
:default-sort-direction="desc"
....
>
```

Comment: What do you mean by just in the beginning?  It's not clear what the issue with `sort-by` is

Comment: I mean the table should be sorted on creation of the page, and not be sortable by the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you don't set `sortable: true` on your `field` items, the default behavior of `<b-table>` is for fields not to be sortable by the user.

So you should use `sort-by` and `sort-desc`:

```html
<b-table
  :sort-by="TheColumnToSort"
  :sort-desc="true"
>
```

Comment: I'm assuming `TheColumnToSort` is a variable.  If it's not, remove the `:` binding from `sort-by`